# Click All Javascript

Tags: javascript

Thanks so much for the help.

Here is the code:

```
    <div class="UserActions   UserActions--small u-textLeft">
    <div class="user-actions btn-group not-following not-muting " data-user-id="1364896129" data-screen-name="VWnews" data-name="Volkswagen USA News" data-protected="false">
      <span class="UserActions-moreActions u-inlineBlock">
          <button type="button" class="js-tooltip unmute-button btn small plain-btn" title="Unmute @VWnews" data-placement="top">
            <span class="Icon Icon--muted Icon--medium"><span class="visuallyhidden">Unmute @VWnews</span></span>
          </button><button type="button" class="first-load js-tooltip mute-button btn small plain-btn" title="Mute @VWnews" data-placement="top">
            <span class="Icon Icon--unmuted Icon--medium"><span class="visuallyhidden">Mute @VWnews</span></span>
          </button>
<div class="dropdown ">
  <button type="button" class="user-dropdown dropdown-toggle js-dropdown-toggle js-link js-tooltip btn plain-btn small-user-dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" data-original-title="More user actions">
    <span class="user-dropdown-icon Icon Icon--cog Icon--small"><span class="visuallyhidden">User Actions</span></span>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <div class="dropdown-caret">
      <span class="caret-outer"></span>
      <span class="caret-inner"></span>
    </div>
    <ul>
```

Trying to click everything containing

`<div class="user-actions btn-group not-following not-muting "`

Answer (score 0):

The string you are attempting to pass to `document.querySelectorAll()` does not have legal quoting and thus causes an error.

The string is this:

```
"[div class='user-actions btn-group not-following not-muting including "']"
```

which seems to have an extra `"` near the end.  Perhaps is should be this:

```
"[div class='user-actions btn-group not-following not-muting including']"
```

But, then looking at that string, I don't see what useful selector you're even making with that.  Selectors don't specify `class='xxx'` in them.

---

Now that you've edited your question a bit, I think you can just use this:

```
$(".user-actions.btn-group.not-following.not-muting").click();
```

This will call the click event on any element that has all of the above classes on it.  Since you're question is tagged with jQuery, I used jQuery for the solution.

In CSS selectors, you precede a classname with a `.` to indicate to the selector query that this is a class name.  If you have multiple class names with no space between them, then all those class names must exist on the same object for it to match.

---

In plain Javascript, you can do this:

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll(".user-actions.btn-group.not-following.not-muting");
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    items[i].click();
}
```

And, you can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/3acy178k/

Comment: @ArturasRosenbacher - I added a new option to the end of my answer.

Comment: Doesnt seem to be running the command, just returning the values in console.

Comment: Trying to run something like

javascript:var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName(''); for(var i=0; i<inputs.length;i++) { inputs[i].click(); }

Comment: @ArturasRosenbacher - the concept of using jQuery's `.click()` to click another element works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/gyd9foq4/.  If it isn't working for you in your page, then you probably have some other issue that is preventing it.  We would have to see the actual code (and HTML) you tried to help you see what is wrong with it.

Comment: If I can convert 

$(".user-actions.btn-group.not-following.not-muting").click();

to javascript. It would work fine. How would I do that?

Comment: @ArturasRosenbacher - If you don't want answers that use jQuery, then remove the jQuery tag from your question.  I've added an option to the end of my answer that works in just plain Javascript.

Comment: Sorry! Fixed the tag issue. Still getting undefined as a result. It can't find that div class for some reason.

Comment: @ArturasRosenbacher - this works in concept (as you can see in my jsFiddle.  So if it isn't working for you, then you are doing something wrong in the implementation which you have not shared with us.  One guess.  When are you calling this code?  Has the page fully loaded before you are calling this code?

Comment: All of the HTML is loaded. Does the extra space in the class make an issue?

Comment: <div class="user-actions btn-group not-following not-muting "

Comment: @ArturasRosenbacher -  The extra space should not matter.  It is considered good housekeeping to not have extra spaces in your HTML class names, but it should not matter for selector matching.

Comment: Why doesn't 

javascript:var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('user-actions btn-group not-following not-muting '); for(var i=0; i<inputs.length;i++) { inputs[i].click(); }

work?

Comment: @ArturasRosenbacher - it works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/hpnpfx3z/

Comment: Seems that the div class does not include the space in the jsfiddle. Added the space there and in the javascript code, undefined result.

Comment: @ArturasRosenbacher - works fine here with the space: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/peg9n2b5/.  You really ought to just use `document.querySelectorAll()` anyway because it's so much more powerful.  I've given you multiple ways that work, I'm a bit tired of chasing you here.